# MQL5 does not allowing the Dynamic Array to store value

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to play with the storage of the MQL 5 Array. When I am not using any `ArrayResize()`, I am getting error:

```
double d [];
d[0] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i< ArraySize(d); i++)
   {
   Print(d[i]);
```

The error is as follows:

```
2018.03.26 13:17:25.379 2018.02.02 00:00:00   array out of range in 'testing.mq5' (69,2)
```

Whereas when I use `ArrayResize()` I get output.

```
double d [];
ArrayResize(d,2);
d[0] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i< ArraySize(d); i++)
   {
   Print(d[i]);
   }
```

Output:  `1`

It worked. But, if I try to add the array element beyond the array size then I get `out of range` error.

I am will to achieve is that the array must remain dynamic in size perspective.
Say I the size given is `2` and during my program the array element at `3` needs to be added then the array must accept it.

I cannot use `ArrayResize()` as it will wipe out other values, which I don't want to happen.
Kindly, suggest me a middle way out so that I can enter any number of values in an array irrespective of its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <Arrays\ArrayObj.mqh>` is good for storing objects of any class, `ArrayInt` for list of integers, `ArrayDouble` for list of doubles and floats. Add as many as you need, whenever you need and you will never have to resize or catch index out of array.

```
CArrayInt *integers;
OnInit(){integers=new CArrayInt();}
OnDeinit(int reason){delete(integers);}
OnTick(){
   integers.Add(0);integers.Add(1);integers.Add(2);
   int firstElem=integers.At(0); firstElem=integers[0];
   int lastElem=integers.At(integers.Total()-1);
   int totalElementsInTheList=integers.Total();
   integers.Delete(2); // delete element with index 2. deleting element that match with the object is not supported in basic API
}
```